# Separate array values into qualifying and non-qualifying arrays

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements, functional-programming, filtering

I'm familiar with array_filter, and I'm trying to think more functional, but I was wondering if there is a way to keep the discarded values? For example, if I had an array like:

```
$arr = array( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
$arrGreaterThanTwo = array_filter($arr, function($item) {
    return $item > 2;
});
```

The results would be: array( 3, 4 ).

1. Is there a way to keep the discarded values array( 1, 2 )?
2. Or do I need to reuse array_filter again on the original array and return item <= to 2?
3. If I use array_filter again to grab array( 1, 2 ), wouldn't that be inefficient by looping over the original array twice?

At the end, I'm just trying to loop over once with array_filter and keep the discarded values too into a separate array.

Comment: Just use a simple foreach loop with a if/else condition then you can add the elements that fulfill your condition into one array and the rest into another.

Comment: It filters the array. That's what it says in the box that's what it does. Just use a foreach loop.

Comment: Looping twice will NOT be inefficient. Try it. Test execution time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function array_partition(array $array, callable $fn){
    $result = [[],[]];
    foreach ( $array as $value ){
        $result[$fn($value)?0:1][]=$value;
    }
    return $result;
}
// example usage:
$res = array_partition([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], function($i) { return $i&1==1;});
```

Although this is not functional implementation it has a functional interface just like `array_filter`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the other array values apart from the ones filtered, use [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

> **array_diff** — Computes the difference of arrays

```
$arrRemaining = array_diff($arr, $arrGreaterThanTwo);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 2
)
```

Comment: I like this answer as it is simple, clean, and understandable. However, correct me if I wrong...this is looping over twice. I will take a crack at my own question and see what other developers think. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: This answer yatta-yattas how `$arrGreaterThanTwo` is defined / what it contains -- it might be unsuitable for many real world scenarios where the blacklisted values cannot be predicted.

Answer (score -1):

Updated Response

```
function test($arrOne, $fn){
  $restArr = [];

  $filterResults = array_filter($arrOne, function($item) use (&$restArr, $fn) {
      if( $fn($item) ) return $item;
      $restArr[] = $item;
  });

  return array( $filterResults, $restArr );
}

print_r( test( array(1,2,3,4), function($item){
  return $item > 2;
} ) );
```

Does anyone have a problem with this?

Comment: Yes, the problem is the global scope of `$restArr`. Better don't use global variables, since side effects generally yield difficult to debug code. The idea is good, but Sylwester's suggestion is much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It makes sense.

Comment: @CamilStaps what about if I wrap this into in its own method or function and return both arrays? Even though $restArr is global, it is only "global" inside the method.

Comment: It works, but it is still a very unclear approach. Imagine coming back to this after a year, will it be clear what this code does? Global variables should be avoided not only because side effects can give undebugable bugs, but also because they make the code much harder to understand. As a side note, (I think) the `&$restArr` could be just `$restArr`, `use` will never pass something by value (not tested).

Comment: I don't know, but I find it harder to read Sylwester's answer than this one. If you pass just $restArr without the &, $restArr will be empty. I really do not see the harm of passing &$restArr because of being inside a function. If it was outside, than yes...bah...maybe it is me that I don't understand.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure about the `use` semantics, thanks for that. Do what you think is best. The two don't differ in complexity. I think most people would find his answer easier to read.

Comment: the use keyword is for closure in php...I'm using an older version of PHP, so I don't know if there is a better syntax of doing it with newer versions. Well, I already gave Sylwester the credit, and I will let it be. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think this should be downvoted because this solution is readable, functional, and efficient.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but usually bad coding practice is a valid downvoting reason.

Comment: Well, I didn't mean you, but whoever did it.

Answer (score -1):

I might recommend you write your own function for it. This is `array_bifilter` – instead of returning one array, it returns two. The first is the *truthy* values, the second is the *falsey* values. And yes, it only iterates thru the input array once.

```
function array_bifilter(array $xs, callable $f) {
  return array_reduce($xs, function ($acc, $x) use ($f) {
    if (call_user_func($f, $x))
      array_push($acc[0], $x);
    else
      array_push($acc[1], $x);
    return $acc;
  }, [[], []]);
}

list($t, $f) = array_bifilter([1,2,3,4], function($x) { return $x > 2; });

echo json_encode(['true' => $t, 'false' => $f], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), PHP_EOL;
```

Output (in JSON format for easy reading)

```
{
    "true": [
        3,
        4
    ],
    "false": [
        1,
        2
    ]
}
```